# PHP cli remote debugger issue

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans, xdebug

I have this problem: I'm trying to debug PHP scripts ran over CLI (I don't care about doing so over a web server) either remotely - preferably - or locally.

I'm on Linux both on the remote server and my development local machine using xdebug, and either netbeans/eclipse remotely or vdebug on vim locally.

So my issue is this: the remote machine runs PHP scripts in the background since we're using them for system tasks, resource monitoring, etc. So while I'm trying to debug script A (which I'm working on), the debugger ends up showing me the cron'ed scripts that are being ran at the same time, making it impossible to work on what I'm doing at the time.

Am I doing something wrong? I've tried a number of approaches but I keep running into this problem.

My current configuration is this, but I've tried a multitude of variations.

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = On
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had xdebug.remote_autostart set. Every PHP script that started ended up being passed through the debugger whether it was the one I was working on or not.

The relevant part of xdebug's documentation is this:
   When running the script from the command line you need to set an environment variable, like:
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=session_name"
php myscript.php

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question your IDE is run on different machine than script runs.
In this case the option

`xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1`

should be the host where your IDE runs.

Make sure you configure `idekey` as well as Eclipse itself properly.

Also make sure that the config you have is in php.ini for CLI, not for Apache.

Comment: Yes. The configuration I'm showing above is the one where I was debugging locally.

Comment: Essentially xdebug "works" in both the remote and a local configuration.

What I can't get it to do is differentiate between the script I actually want it to debug and any other PHP script which happens to be executed at the same time.

Comment: Will using different `idekey` help probably?